# Cordova: accept payments like a POS

Tags: cordova, payment, pos, cordova-ios, cordova-android

What we're looking for a plugin that allows one of our applications to act like a POS, in order to accept Google Pay, Apple Pay, or contactless cards (debit/credit) payments.

Has anyone any suggestion about that?